# c++ put functions in separate source files

Tags: c++, function

Currently I have an unique source file (*.cpp) where all my functions are working right. Now i'm trying to take some of them out into separate source files and including them into main source with no success.

My current project is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#define _SQLNCLI_ODBC_
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqlncli.h>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;


/*This is one of the functions to be put in separate file:*/
string *ReadPageAsignations ( const char* RutayNombre, const char* Page )
{
bool MisionCumplida = false;
bool EncabezadoListo = false;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
char * pch;
char istr[256];
const int NUM_DATA = 15;    
static string data[NUM_DATA];
std::stringstream InputString;
ifstream inputFile(RutayNombre); 

if (inputFile.is_open())        
  {
  while (inputFile.good() && MisionCumplida == false)
    {
        i = 0;
        inputFile.getline(istr,256);
        pch = strtok (istr,":");
        if (string(pch) == "[Pagina]")
        {
            EncabezadoListo = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EncabezadoListo = false;
        }
        if (string(pch) == Page)
        {
            MisionCumplida = true;
        }
        while (pch != NULL)
            {
                if ((EncabezadoListo == true) || (MisionCumplida == true))
                {
                    data[i] = data[i] + " " + string(pch);
                }
                pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
                i++;
            }
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return data;
  }
} //End of function 'ReadPageAsignations'

/*This is another function where my function "ReadPageAsignations' get called -- btw, I want also this function to be in a separate source file.*/
void DeliverHtml (const char* page){//const char* RutayNombre ) {
  string *p;
  char * pch;
  size_t pos;
  string RutayNombre;
RutayNombre = "../Substructure/Templates/" + SearchConfigValue( "../Substructure/Conf/Config-Templates.txt", "htmlTemplate:");
const char *RutayNombreConfigCompos = "../Substructure/Conf/Config-Composition.txt";
  string RutayNombreParaInsertar;
  string token, token1, token2;
  string line, lineRead, lineToInsert;
  char * StrToTokenize2;
  string StrToTokenize1;
p=ReadPageAsignations( RutayNombreConfigCompos, page); //Here, I call the function I want in a separate file
...
}

/*And here is the main() function*/
int main()
{
char *value = "page=Home";
    if (NULL!=strstr(getenv("QUERY_STRING"), "page="))
    {
        value = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
    }


  char *posCh = strstr(value, "=");

    DeliverHtml(&posCh[0]+1);
return 0;
}
```

For the first function, I have tried creating the header file 'ReadPageAsignations.h' and a source file 'ReadPageAsignations.cpp'.

Header file 'ReadPageAsignations.h' containing:

```
#ifndef READPAGEASIGNATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define READPAGEASIGNATIONS_H_INCLUDED

string *ReadPageAsignations ( const char* RutayNombre, const char* Page );

#endif // READPAGEASSIGNATIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

Source file 'ReadPageAsignations.cpp' for separate function containing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;

string *ReadPageAsignations ( const char* RutayNombre, const char* Page )
{
bool MisionCumplida = false;
bool EncabezadoListo = false;
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
char * pch;
char istr[256];
const int NUM_DATA = 15;    /*El numero de elementos debe coincidir con el iterador en la función Deliverhtml.*/
static string data[NUM_DATA];
std::stringstream InputString;
ifstream inputFile(RutayNombre); //Abre el archivo y lo asigna al stream inputFile.

if (inputFile.is_open())        //Chequea que el archivo esté abierto.
  {
  while (inputFile.good() && MisionCumplida == false)
    {
        i = 0;
        inputFile.getline(istr,256);
        pch = strtok (istr,":");
        if (string(pch) == "[Pagina]")
        {
            EncabezadoListo = true;
        }
        else
        {
            EncabezadoListo = false;
        }
        if (string(pch) == Page)
        {
            MisionCumplida = true;
        }
        while (pch != NULL)
            {
                if ((EncabezadoListo == true) || (MisionCumplida == true))
                {
                    data[i] = data[i] + " " + string(pch);
                }
                pch = strtok (NULL, ",");
                i++;
            }
    }
    inputFile.close();
    return data;
  }
} //End function
```

and, main project containing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#define _SQLNCLI_ODBC_
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqlncli.h>

#include "ReadPageAsignations.h" //Here I #include the function definition file (header)

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::ifstream;
...
}
```

I've got a lot of compiling errors:

```
\ReadPageAsignations.h|4|error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'|
\ReadPageAsignations.h|4|error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int|
\ReadPageAsignations.h|4|error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int|
main.cpp|20|error C2872: 'string' : ambiguous symbol|
...
```

I'm working Code::blocks 13.12 with MS Visual C++ 2005/2008 compiler.

any help will be highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: your header ReadPageAsignations.h needs to include `<string>` and the source file needs to include the header

Comment: I would suggest you to start with a smaller example. Use less code and try to get it right, then you also know how to do it on your real project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put `#include <string>` in your header file and remove it from your .cpp file

as following:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#define _SQLNCLI_ODBC_
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqlncli.h>
#include "ReadPageAsignations.h"
...
```

note: including header file with the same name of .cpp file , include both.

ReadPageAsignations.h

```
#ifndef READPAGEASIGNATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#define READPAGEASIGNATIONS_H_INCLUDED
#include <string>        //<-----This line, include string header

std::string *ReadPageAsignations ( const char* RutayNombre, const char* Page );

#endif // READPAGEASSIGNATIONS_H_INCLUDED
```

ReadPageAsignations.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include "ReadPageAsignations.h"  // <--- add the header file here
//#include <string>   <---remove it already included in the header file


using namespace std;
//using std::cout;  <--remove this you already used namespace std
//using std::ifstream;  <--remove this you already used namespace std

string *ReadPageAsignations ( const char* RutayNombre, const char* Page )
{

... } //End function
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is telling you that when it tried to parse the header file it encountered the symbol `string` and doesn't recognize it. Adding `#include <string>` to your header file and fully qualifying the `string` type as `std::string` should correct the problem.

Comment: imho including everything in the header isnt the best. Instead I would include in the header everything needed by the header and not more.

Comment: Fair enough. It will certainly cut down on compile time that way. I'll change my answer.